# How in R to set default action for S3 class?

Tags: r

For most S3 objects in R, simply typing the object name into the command line (e.g. `obj`) produces the same output as `print(obj)`. When defining new methods for a class, how do we setup this property such that a default action is performed when the name is typed into command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straightforward. *print* is the default. Setting up the print.newobject method sets this action.